# Why organic materials' hole mobility is usually higher than electron mobility?

Tags: scattering, semiconductor-physics

Most of OFETs, and in particular OTFTs, are p-type (p-channel devices), because the hole mobility is higher than the electron mobility in most organic materials ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_field-effect_transistor#Materials)).

What is the reason for this? Isn't hole scattering in the valence band is more prominant than electron scattering in the conduction band in both organic and inorganic materials?